# Add a button for a functionality on youtube

Tags: youtube

I need to add a button on the youtube interface close to the caption if possible. To link to the video in other languages. remaining on youtube directly.

Someone has an idea how it will be possible to implement that. I need an hint, from where I can begin to build it, or if it exist a solution thanks to let me know.

Comment: Are you asking how to change youtube? seriously?

Comment: nono how to can add a functionality. :-D sorry my english suck

Comment: That still doesn't explain what it is you're trying to do (And *still* sounds like you want to change youtube)

Comment: Ok. I need to link the first video in English to:

- other video in other languages

it is more clear like that?

Comment: No, because that's a "user requirement" at best, but it says nothing about how you want that to work. You say you want to add a button. Where do you want to add it to?

Comment: First, thank to reply to my question.

Currently I am not so good in web development ( I know only HTML and CSS) or programming languages like python or Java, but nothing of javascript, jQurey and so on.  that's why my question is so general. 

I will probably need to learn a lot to can implement what I want to do.

Ok the main idea is to add a button somewhere ( where is legally and the implementation possible). To connect the first video in English to other video dubbed in other languages. (like youtube do for the transaltion, but for dubbed video)

Comment: I need to know how I can try to do that, what which languages/API to stay in the legally and possible. And have a general idea what I will have to learn for, if something doesn't already exist. That's it

Comment: The only thing that resembles what you're talking about is annotations that can be inserted to a video clip. It's a feature that exists in youtube itself, and I guess it's done maually while editing the video on youtube (haven't done this myself)